# Complex Analysis textbook for engineering

Tags: complex-analysis

I’m an EE grad student. 
I’m already familiar with complex analysis, but I’m missing more advanced topics as Riemann surfaces. I’m not interested in mathematics books with theorems and proofs, I just need an intuitive explanation.

If you want to know the reason, I’m reading Felsen book about asymptotic evaluation of integrals and Green’s function in layered media and I’d need a deeper understanding for surface waves and leaky waves (so critical points, Riemann surfaces).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Visual Complex Analysis* by Tristan Needham covers Riemann surfaces and applications of complex analysis in physics. The book's aim is to promote an intuitive geometric understanding of the concepts of complex analysis.

Comment: Seems like a nice book, but I can't find the section related to Riemann surfaces. Are you sure it's there?

Comment: @idontsink : I misremembered. Needham covers the Riemann sphere, but not Riemann surfaces in general.